# How to secure Web Service API integration with external systems

Tags: api, integration, security

I am given few URLs (web service APIs), which when called would fetch and display data in JSON format and I am using these in my Salesforce Org and use them to update few of Salesforce fields. I have written an APEX controller to parse the data coming from the external application and then use it another main controller wherein the actions such as insert/update take place. Like, whenever a Lead record is opened, then a call is made to the external system using the URL provided, then fetch the data and insert/update data as per the need.

I am wondering if there could be a security be placed whenever there is a call made to the external system from Salesforce, as of now nothing of such is maintained and I assume there should be one existing and need suggestions on this.

Answer (score 0):

A few reasons that the external URLs would be secured are:

- The data obtained from them is not public information and only authorized clients should be able to access it e.g. someones personal details or things like bank account details.
- The URLs allow the data to be changed and only authorized clients should be allowed to make changes.
- There is a concern that the URLs might be overloaded with requests e.g. unexpected clients start to use the URLs because they available.

If none of these apply - the data is fine for anyone to see, the data is not updated, and the data is of no interest to others - you could leave the access unauthenticated.

If the access does need to be authenticated, the technique you use will depend on what is available on the server you access via the URLs - there are a variety of techniques.

Comment: Thank you for the information shared above. Does the authentication on the URLs need to be done at SFDC side as I am told that they are already passed the authentication protocol from my 3rd arty provider.

Comment: The reason for me to post this query is that I had been facing few troubles with Salesforce1 as the visaulforce pages that I wrote aren't displaying on the app. And when contacted Salesdforce, I am told that **He indicated it also appears to be calling out to an external integration or something. - This would lead us to believe the issues lie in the code, and how its optomized. We really need it to be optimized for Mobile use.** and so I was wondering if it might be with authentication for related to the URLs.

Comment: @Sapthagiri If your callouts are server-side, then I don't see the connection with the client side rendering i.e. something that works in normal Visualforce should work in Salesforce1. But I may be misunderstanding your comments.

Comment: I am not sure either because, I had another application that also fetches data using URLs which did (Visualforce pages did show up) work on Salesforce1 however, this particular one, where I am calling 4 web service URLs (from the same provider) is not showing up on Salesforce1!